# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php, pdo

Saludos al intentar ingresar información en mi base de datos mediandte consultas preparadas en php PDO me genera los siguientes errores en primer lugar al intentar subir una imagen a una carpeta del servidor y su ruta a la bd y luego otro error al intentar pasar por bindvalue un objeto Datetime:

Warning: Undefined array key "imagen" in C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\pagar.php on line 37

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\pagar.php on line 37

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\pagar.php:106 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\pagar.php(106): PDOStatement->bindValue(':fecha_pago', Object(DateTime), 2) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\pagar.php on line 106

```
1  <?php 
   2  $nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
   3  $apellido=!empty($_POST['apellido']) ? $_POST['apellido'] : NULL;
   4  $letras=!empty($_POST['letras']) ? $_POST['letras'] : NULL;
   5  $documento=!empty($_POST['documento']) ? $_POST['documento'] : NULL;
   6  $banco=!empty($_POST['banco']) ? $_POST['banco'] : NULL;
   7  $numero_cuenta=!empty($_POST['numero_cuenta']) ? $_POST['numero_cuenta'] : NULL;
   8  $referencia=!empty($_POST['referencia']) ? $_POST['referencia'] : NULL;
   9  $monto=!empty($_POST['monto']) ? $_POST['monto'] : NULL;
   10 $imagen=!empty($_POST['imagen']) ? $_POST['imagen'] : NULL;
   11 $estatus=1;
   12 
   13 
   14 session_start();
   15 include "./php/conexion.php";
   16 
   17 if(!isset($_SESSION['datos_logueo'])){
   18   $url="login.php?error=Para poder pagar su plan debe iniciar sesión o registrarse";
   19  
   20 }
   21 $idp=$_GET['id_plan'];
   22 if( isset($_GET['id_plan'])){
   23   $sql="select * from planes where id_plan=".$_GET['id_plan'];
   24   $resultado=$conexion->prepare($sql);
   25   $resultado->execute();
   26 
   27   while($fila=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   28       
   29     $duracion = $fila['duracion'];
   30
   31      
   32           
   33           $fecha = new DateTime();
   34           $fecha_venc = new DateTime();
   35           $fecha_venc->modify( sprintf( '%+d months', intval( $duracion ) ) );    
   38           $carpeta="./imagenes/capturaspagos/"; 
   37           $nombre_foto= $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
   38           
   39           //imagen.algo.jpg
   40           $temp= explode( '.' ,$nombre_foto);
   41           $extension= end($temp);
   42       
   43           $nombrefinal = time().'.'.$extension;
   44           if(!empty($_FILES['imagen']['name'])){  
   45           if(mime_content_type($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']) =='image/png' || 
   46  mime_content_type($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'])=='image/jpeg'){
   47           if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $carpeta.$nombrefinal)){ 
   48           $sql1 = ("insert into pagos
   49             
 50(nombre,apellido,tipo_doc,documento,banco,numero_cuenta,referencia,fecha_pago,fecha_vencimiento,monto,51 imagen,
52                id_usuario,id_plan,id_estatus) values
53                54(:nombre,:apellido,:tipo_doc,:documento,:banco,:numero_cuenta,:referencia,:fecha_pago,:fecha_vencimient55 o,:monto,:imagen,:id_usuario,:id_plan,:estatus)");
56              $stmt=$conexion->prepare($sql1);
57              $stmt->bindValue(":nombre", $nombre,PDO::PARAM_STR);
58              $stmt->bindValue(":apellido", $apellido,PDO::PARAM_STR);
59              $stmt->bindValue(":tipo_doc", $letras,PDO::PARAM_STR);
60
61              $stmt->bindValue(":documento", $documento,PDO::PARAM_STR);
62              $stmt->bindValue(":banco", $banco,PDO::PARAM_STR);
63              $stmt->bindValue(":numero_cuenta", $numero_cuenta,PDO::PARAM_INT);
64              $stmt->bindValue(":referencia",$referencia,PDO::PARAM_INT);
65              $stmt->bindValue(":fecha_pago",$fecha,PDO::PARAM_STR);
66              $stmt->bindValue(":fecha_vencimiento",$fecha_venc,PDO::PARAM_STR);
67              $stmt->bindValue(":monto",$monto,PDO::PARAM_STR);
68              $stmt->bindValue(":imagen",$nombrefinal,PDO::PARAM_STR);
69              $stmt->bindValue(":id_usuario",$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
70              $stmt->bindValue(":id_plan",$idp,PDO::PARAM_INT);
71              $stmt->bindValue(":estatus",1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
72              $stmt->execute();
73              $url="../index.php?success";        
74          //SI SE REALIZA LA SUBIDA REALIZO EL INSERT   
75        }else{
76          $url="planes.php?error=No se pudo subir la imagen"; 
77
78         }
79      
80      }else{
81       
82          $url="planes.php?error=Por favor subir imagen jpg o png";  
83        
84      } 
85    
86    }
87      
88      else{
89
90              $sql2 =("insert into pagos
91                92(nombre,apellido,tipo_doc,documento,banco,numero_cuenta,referencia,fecha_pago,fecha_vencimiento,monto,
93                id_usuario,id_plan,id_estatus) values
94                95(:nombre,:apellido,:letras,:documento,:banco,:numero_cuenta,:referencia,:fecha_pago,:fecha_vencimiento,96 :monto,:id_usuario,:id_plan,:estatus)");
97              $stmt2=$conexion->prepare($sql2);
98              $stmt2->bindValue(":nombre", $nombre,PDO::PARAM_STR);
99              $stmt2->bindValue(":apellido", $apellido,PDO::PARAM_STR);
100             $stmt2->bindValue(":tipo_doc", $letras,PDO::PARAM_STR);
101             $stmt2->bindValue(":documento", $documento,PDO::PARAM_STR);
102             $stmt2->bindValue(":banco", $banco,PDO::PARAM_STR);
103             $stmt2->bindValue(":numero_cuenta", $numero_cuenta,PDO::PARAM_INT);
104             $stmt2->bindValue(":referencia",$referencia,PDO::PARAM_INT);
105             $stmt2->bindValue(":fecha_pago",$fecha,PDO::PARAM_STR);
106             $stmt2->bindValue(":fecha_vencimiento",$fecha_venc,PDO::PARAM_STR);
107             $stmt2->bindValue(":monto",$monto,PDO::PARAM_STR);
108             $stmt2->bindValue(":id_isuario",$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
109             $stmt2->bindValue(":id_plan",$idp,PDO::PARAM_INT);
110             $stmt2->bindValue(":estatus",1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
111             $stmt2->execute();
112             $url="../index.php?success";    
113     
114         }   
115        
116      }
117    }
118    ?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="pagar.php?id_plan=<?php echo $_GET['id_plan']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="nombre">Nombre(s) del titular de la cuenta</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="30"  id="nombre"  name="nombre" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="nombre del titular de la cuenta o nombre de la empresa si es juridica">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="apellido">Apellidos</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="30"  id="apellido"  name="apellido" autocomplete="off" placeholder="apellido del titular de la cuenta">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="tipo_doc">Tipo de documento del titular de la cuenta</label>    
                <select name="tipo" class="form-control" onchange="cambia()">
                <option data-lenght="8" value="1">C.I.
                <option data-lenght="9" value="2">R.I.F
                <option data-lenght="10" value="3">Pasaporte
                </select>
                 </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="tipo_doc">Prefijo del tipo de documento</label> 
                <select name="letras" id="letras" class="form-control">
                <option value="V">V
                <option value="E">E
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="documento">Documento</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  maxlength="8" onkeyup="mascara(this,'.',patron1,true)" onkeypress="return ValidarNumeros(event)" autocomplete="off" name="documento" placeholder="escriba el número de cédula, rif ó pasaporte según sea el caso" id="documento" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="banco">Banco desde donde se hizo la transferencia</label>
            <select id="banco" class="form-control" name="banco" >
            <option selected></option>
            <option value="100% BANCO">100% BANCO
            <option value="ABN AMRO BANK">ABN AMRO BANK
            <option value="BANCAMIGA">BANCAMIGA 
            <option value="BANCO ACTIVO">BANCO ACTIVO 
            <option value="BANCO AGRICOLA">BANCO AGRICOLA
            <option value="BANCO BANESCO">BANCO BANESCO
            <option value="BANCO BICENTENARIO">BANCO BICENTENARIO
            <option value="BANCO CARONI">BANCO CARONI
            <option value="BANCO DE VENENEZUELA">BANCO DE VENENEZUELA 
            <option value="BANCO DEL CARIBE">BANCO DEL CARIBE 
            <option value="BANCO DEL TESORO">BANCO DEL TESORO
            <option value="BANCO ESPIRITO SANTO">BANCO ESPIRITO SANTO
            <option value="BANCO EXTERIOR">BANCO EXTERIOR
            <option value="BANCO INTERNACIONAL DE DESARROLLO">BANCO INTERNACIONAL DE DESARROLLO
            <option value="BANCO MERCANTIL">BANCO MERCANTIL
            <option value="BANCO NACIONAL DE CREDITO">BANCO NACIONAL DE CREDITO
            <option value="BANCO B.O.D">BANCO B.O.D
            <option value="BANCO PLAZA">BANCO PLAZA
            <option value="BANCO PROVINCIAL BBVA">BANCO PROVINCIAL BBVA
            <option value="BANCO VENEZOLANO DE CREDITO">BANCO VENEZOLANO DE CREDITO
            <option value="BANCRECER">BANCRECER 
            <option value="BANFANB">BANFANB
            <option value="BANGENTE">BANGENTE
            <option value="BANPLUS">BANPLUS
            <option value="CITIBANK">CITIBANK
            <option value="DELSUR">DELSUR
            <option value="FONDO COMUN">FONDO COMUN
            <option value="INSTITUTO MUNICIPAL DE CREDITO POPULAR">INSTITUTO MUNICIPAL DE CREDITO POPULAR
            <option value="MIBANCA">MIBANCA
            <option value="SOFITASA">SOFITASA
        </select>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="numero_cuenta">Número de cuenta del banco desde donde transfirió</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return ValidarNumeros(event)" id="numero_cuenta"  name="numero_cuenta" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Número de cuenta del banco desde donde transfirió">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="referencia">Número de Referencia de la transferencia</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return ValidarNumeros(event)"  id="referencia"  name="referencia" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Número de cuenta del banco desde donde transfirió">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="monto">Monto de la transferencia</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="monto" name="monto"  placeholder="Monto en Bs.S de la transferencia realizada">
    </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="imagen">Captura de la transferencia (Opcional)</label>
        <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="margin:0px 470px;">
<button class="primary-btn order-submit">Pagar</button>
</div>
</form>
                            
                    
                    
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
            
                <div class="row">
                </div>
            
            </div>
        
        </div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_FILES);`? En cuanto al problema con la fecha, debes convertir el objeto a cadena para insertarla, por ejemplo: `$sfecha_venc= $fecha_venc-> format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );` Y luego: `$stmt2->bindValue(":fecha_vencimiento",$sfecha_venc,PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, `array(0) { }` esto muestra.

Comment: Entonces no se está enviando ningún archivo o está habiendo algún problema con él, por ejemplo, si el archivo excede el tamaño máximo permitido no llegaría. Deberías establecer controles para verificar que está pasando con el archivo.

Comment: No, es que ese error lo está dando sin siquiera cargar la página, el array logicamente muestra cero porque el input donde va la imagen está vacío, nadie ha cargado nada.

Comment: Warning: Undefined variable $fecha in line 34 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\elmercader\pagar.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in line 34

Comment: Luego de pasar la fecha a cadena $fecha= $fecha-> format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ); me da ese warning y ese error también

Comment: haciéndoles un `var_dump();` las las dos fechas después de pasarlas a cadena ambas tienen valor  `NULL`

Comment: Cuando algo no funciona tú tienes que verificarlo, para eso es `var_dump`. Entonces verifica el dato con el que creas las fechas, puede que esté vacío o no venga en un formato válido.

Comment: Listo corregido el problema por esa parte, gracias por responder

Comment: ¿Ya lo resolviste?

Comment: Si las fechas y la imagen listo, pero me sigue generando errores por ejemplo en la línea 30 y 31 en el WHILE la variable duración que se supone que la  traigo con el select le tuve que asignar un valor directo para probar que sumara la fecha_vencimiento y tampoco me trae los demás datos que quiero mostrar de esa consulta en la linea 287 y 298... Me muestra Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in e buscado este error e intento corregir y nada

Comment: También Warning: Undefined variable $fila in C:\xampp\htdocs\elmercader\pagar.php on line 284

Comment: Más de lo mismo: **depura tu código** haciendo `var_dump` de todo aquello que falle y si sale nulo o con los datos que no esperas o como no lo esperas, revisa dónde se producen esas variables / objetos / datos hasta dar con el problema. Sugiero que aprendas bien a depurar tu código, te aseguro que luego te vas a ahorrar horas, días, semanas... y muchos dolores de cabeza buscando dónde puede estar el problema. Haz las depuraciones y nos dices el resultado.

Comment: Por **depurar** me refiero a que, si en este contexto: `while($fila=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){` tienes un problema con algún dato que proviene de `$fila`, como es `$duracion`, hagas esto: `var_dump($fila);` Así verás lo que hay en la fila, y verás por qué la variable `$duracion` no está asumiendo el valor que crees debería asumir. ...Y así con todas las partes del código donde tengas problemas. Saber **depurar** es una de las cosas más importantes en programación, de las más fáciles de aprender, pero veo que por lo general se le dedica poco tiempo a aprender a hacerlo.

Comment: Perfecto he tomado su consejo de hecho desde que me escribió ayer que usará el var_dump(); en las fechas lo he hecho con todo lo que me ha dado error así corregí el de las imágenes y las fechas, también le había hecho un var_dump(); a la variable $fila y trae un valor nulo, intente corregir la consulta e igual.

Comment: Además de que algo está sucediendo porque ahora cuando le hago `var_dump();` a cualquier variable no muestra nada, hago un `var_dump();` en cualquiera de los otros archivos y me muestra el contenido de las variables su tipo al igual que de los arreglos pero en este módulo no me quiere mostrar nada, no entiendo el porque